# Search multiple table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have this tables: [image]

And I need to get the "nome" from the table "produtos" that were sold in the present year (from the vendas -> data column). How can I relate the table those table ? I know I have to use the foreigns keys...

Comment: It's a simple `JOIN`. Any SQL tutorial should explain how to join tables.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key constraint is not required.

Relational databases establish "relationships" between rows by storing common values in columns.

Can you write a query that returns rows from `vendas` that represent "sold in the current year"?

```
SELECT v.id
  FROM `vendas` v
 WHERE ...
```

Can you then write a query that returns that same set, along with matching rows from `produtos_vendidos` ?

```
SELECT v.id
     , pv.id_venda
     , pv.id_produto
  FROM `vendas` v
  JOIN `produtos_vendidos` pv
    ON pv.id_venda = v.id
 WHERE ...
```

Once you have that, you can add a join to `produtos`

```
SELECT v.id
     , p.*
  FROM `vendas` v
  JOIN `produtos_vendidos` pv
    ON pv.id_venda = v.id
  JOIN `produtos` p
    ON p.id = pv.id_produtos
 WHERE ...
```

It's very likely that this will return multiple copies of rows from `produtos`.

To eliminate those duplicates, we could use a `GROUP BY` clause, or we can rewrite the query.

One possible approach is to use an EXISTS predicate with a correlated subquery. As an example of what that might look like:

```
 SELECT p.*
   FROM `produtos` p
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM `vendas` v
                   JOIN `produtos_vendidos` pv
                     ON pv.id_venda = v.id
                  WHERE pv.id_produtos = p.id
                    AND ...
               )
```

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.